# Git doesn't seem to want to keep local refs to origin/master

Tags: git

First: apologies for the question title, I don't actually know what the problem is so I don't know how to ask about it.

I want to diff my master with upstream master (should be origin/master, based on the way my remotes are set up).

But: origin was put there *after* I had been working on it locally for a while, so it's "origin" in name only. That is: I had a local repo, put it up into a gitolite setup, and then told my local git to call it origin.

These are the symptoms:

```
$ git diff master orgin/master
fatal: ambiguous argument 'orgin/master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.

$ git diff master origin/master --
fatal: bad revision 'origin/master'
```

Hm.

```
$ git remote -v
origin  git@example.com:example (fetch)
origin  git@example.com:example (push)
```

okay, that looks right.

```
$ git branch -a
... # nothing from origin
```

Hm.

```
$ git fetch -a origin
From example.com:example
* branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
```

I have no idea if that's correct. It looks productive, but `git diff master origin/master` still fails, and:

```
$ git branch --track omaster origin/master
fatal: Not a valid object name: 'origin/master'.
```

Wha?

```
$ ls .git/refs/remotes
gitps  ps
```

That looks wrong: those are old remotes that haven't existed for months. Also they're empty. And `.git/remotes` doesn't exist at all, although I'm not sure that it should.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may need to tell git which branches to fetch from origin.  In the `.git/config` file for this repo, under the `[remote "origin"]` section, there should be a line like `fetch = ...`.  This tells git what to fetch and where to put it locally.  Here's a pretty standard example:

```
[remote "origin"]
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
        url = ssh://...
```

If you don't see the `fetch = ...` line, you can safely add it to match the example, which is the standard "track all branches and call them origin/*branch* locally" option set up by `git clone`.

See the [git pro book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec) for a good description of what's going on.

Comment: Thanks. For me, my fetch line existed, but was only fetching from a particular release branch for some reason.  I updated the line to the above and did `git remote update` and then `git reset --hard origin/branchname` and everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 11):

Have you tried `git remote update`? This will update all remotes, creating remote-tracking branches as needed.

Comment: Just tried it, exactly the same result as `git fetch -a origin`, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue just now. I discovered that my local .git directory as actually a file

```
$ file .git
     .git: ASCII text
```

I deleted the file, and initialized the git repository

```
git init && git remote add origin "gitrepo"
```

Not too sure why this happened. Hopefully this can help someone..